# MYSQL NEIGHBOUR ROWS along with CURRENT ROW

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0, mysqli-multi-query

MYSQL query to fetch the neighbour rows along with the present(id) given condition

like

```
ID | BOOK     |
--------------
1  | xyzbooks |

2  | pqrbooks |

3  | dnsaddds |

4  | dfbsakjf |

5  | dbsadbdd |

6  | tyrbooks |

7  | sfdffdsf |

8  | yuibooks |
```

I am on id 3 (dnsaddds which i could get from url) and i searched for books .
Now I need to fetch the row data of 3rd row, and next and previous results of searched text (books)

RESULT EXPECTED is as follows

```
ID | BOOK     | AUTHOR | DATE
---------------------------
2  | pqrbooks | fbsdjf | 2013

3  | dnsaddds | fdsfbs | 2012

6  | tyrbooks | fdsdff | 2011
```

Looking for a single query with out unions etc..

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select id, book, author, date
from t
where id = 3
      OR id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM t WHERE id < 3)
      OR id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM t WHERE id > 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `union`ing together the three rows that you want:

```
(select id, book, author, date
 from t
 where id = 3
) union all
(select id, book, author, date
 from t
 where id < 3 and book like '%books%'
 order by id desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select id, book, author, date
 from t
 where id > 3 and book like '%books%'
 order by id
 limit 1
)
```

Comment: @NaveenKumar . . . Any particular reason?